# PKCS#12 (.pfx .p12) generation with node.js on the fly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, certificate

I have a certain need to generate them on the fly. While I guess I could use openssl commands to generate files, then read them and delete them, it would be nice if there was a way to do it inside of node.js.

Any suggestions? I checked out [certgen](https://github.com/bcle/certgen) but it doesn't have what I'm looking for (plus, it is just calling command line commands and generating files...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Forge to generate PKCS#12 files in node.js:

https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#pkcs12

Answer (score 1):

I had the same demand.

If you know C++ you can write a module to link against OpenSSL directly.

If not (like me) then you're essentially stuck to CLI calls.

PS: I'd definitely avoid writing code to do certificate generation on my own. For highly security related code IMHO it's always better to re-use a trusted and well-established product such as OpenSSL.

Comment: Of course I will use OpenSSL, but I did not want to write a C++ wrapper around it. I guess I know what I will be doing tomorrow. Thankfully, I do know C++ :)

Comment: If you want to do people (including me ;-)) a big favour, it would be super-awesome if could release it as open-source …

Comment: After checking the openssl command line utility's source code, I expect to do this within the next 7 days. I have to, so there's no excuses. Hopefully it isn't full of bugs :)

Comment: What do you think about releasing it to the wild ;-)?

Comment: First let me finish it, then test it to ensure its quality. Just don't expect it to posses a marvelous API designed for flexibility and enhancements, since I need it for a very specific use case :) but, other than that, sure.